# How to make a Priming Manifold on top of my pool pump lid

Tags: pool, pump

I have been thinking about making something like this for a while to help me prime the pool pump at the beginning of the season. Today I found a picture of exactly what I am thinking about. [image]

Can you help me identify what parts are used in this picture or what parts I can use to make something similar?

What is the best way to  seal the metal pipe to the plastic cover to avoid any leaks?

Comment: Do you need the hose fitting for your pump (fill the pump with water), Or are you letting the air out? My pump I have to let the air out it is below the water line.

Comment: I need to fill it with water, not let the air out.

Comment: Don't forget the air does have to come out somewhere, you can't put water in without the air having a place to escape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a brass bulkhead fitting with Orings. [like this photo](https://www.google.com/search?q=bulkhead+fitting+brass&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=979&tbm=isch&imgil=buNu78xyxlgLJM%253A%253Bb9iLXQr0Ee_-nM%253Bhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fstore.homebrewheaven.com%25252Fthru-wall-bulkhead-fitting----brass-12-npt-p728.aspx&source=iu&pf=m&fir=buNu78xyxlgLJM%253A%252Cb9iLXQr0Ee_-nM%252C_&usg=__Nur4cFrUM1mWeIsEqO76UHcNN_M%3D&ved=0ahUKEwi415ed8M_MAhXEKGMKHc_rDBsQyjcIYA&ei=cgUyV7jWPMTRjAPP17PYAQ#imgrc=buNu78xyxlgLJM%3A) shows. Add your threaded shutoff valve and hose adapter and you will be good to go. Be careful when cutting the hole if using a standard drill bit they grab and want to break the plastic. A hole saw would be a better way to reduce the chance of breaking. For a 1/2" pipe a 7/8" hole saw for 3/4"pipe 1-1/8" hole saw are the standard sizes.

Comment: I ended up buying [this](http://www.amazon.com/RainPro-Barrel-Quarter-Bulkhead-Fitting/dp/B00TAN4NLU?ie=UTF8&psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o02_s00). I also bought a 1-1/4 inch hole saw from home depot to make a clean hole (not 1-1/8, because the product page said 1-1/4, which worked perfectly). Here is a  [picture](http://imgur.com/sOugO8o) of my finished product.

Comment: It looks as nice as the photo you had good job!

Answer (score 0):

Making a connection between dissimilar materials (hard/brass and soft/plastic) is difficult. For the best result, it is helpful to transition with one or more materials with in-between stiffness, and/or attach the valve to a wide plate and use a rubber gasket to prevent leaks/failure.

I believe that a good place to start would be to look for water heater pressure relief valve parts. Maybe it would be cheaper to get an old one from a scrap yard that you can cut apart. Or, try looking for some rain barrel parts or study the rainbarrel construction methods. As for the glue, once again, in-between stiffness is the best. Epoxy, silicone, calk, and silicone-caulk blends might all be useful.